# How to determine current JSF lifecycle phase in the code

Tags: jsf, lifecycle

I'm using JSF version `1.2_09-b02-FCS`

Let I've an inner class `TableList` of some other class:

```
private class TableList extends AbstractList<T> {

    private List<T> list;

    private int size;

    public T get(int i) {
        if (needToUpdateList || currPage != i / pageSize) {
            currPage = i / pageSize;
            list = getDataList(currPage * pageSize, pageSize);
            needToUpdateList = false;
        }
        return list.get(i % pageSize);
    }

    public int size() {
        if (needToUpdateSize) {
            size = getDataSize();
            needToUpdateSize = false;
        }
        return size;
    }
}
```

whose get method is going to invoke during the JSF lifecycle phases. The problem is that i don't want to invoke `list = getDataList(currPage * pageSize, pageSize);` suring the render response phase. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if [`FacesContext#getRenderResponse()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#getRenderResponse()) returns true.

```
if (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getRenderResponse()) {
    // We're currently in the render response phase.
}
```

---

In case you're using JSF 2.0, you shouldn't use that method, but instead [`FacesContext#getCurrentPhaseId()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#getCurrentPhaseId()) because the `getRenderResponse()` falsely returns `false` during render response of an initial GET request.